# Change the color of the text in generated pdf file in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm generating a pdf file using Crystal Report.
But i want to change the color of text of that pdf.
How can i do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

- In the Crystal Reports editor, select the item(s) whose colour you want to change and right-click on one of them, then select Format Text... or Format Objects as appropriate.
- To change the colour of the text, select the Font tab in the Format Editor dialog and select the desired colour from the Color dropdown.
- To change the colour of the background to the text (if required), select the Border tab in the Format Editor dialog, check the Color: Background tick box and select the desired colour from the Background dropdown.
- Click the OK button in the Format Editor to confirm the changes to the items' format.